# Error Using Length() Method in Array Within a For Loop

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, indexoutofboundsexception, variable-length

I created an array within a for loop to generate the cube of 1-9 in descending order. My code appears to work as I am able to run it without any syntax or runtime errors. However, whenever I try to use the length() method in my for loop, I get an "array out of bounds exception".

Here is my code without the length() method:

```
/**
 * This method prints out a cubes from one to nine in descending order
 */
public static void cubes()
{
    // create a fixed length array and hard code index number
    int[] values = new int[9];
    values[0] = 1;
    values[1] = 2;
    values[2] = 3;
    values[3] = 4;
    values[4] = 5;
    values[5] = 6;
    values[6] = 7;
    values[7] = 8;
    values[8] = 9;
    // Create variable to store cubed numbers
    double cubedNumber = 0;
    // Create for loop to run the array from 1-9 in descending order
    for (int counter = 8; counter > 0; counter--)
    {
        cubedNumber = Math.pow(values[counter], 3);
        System.out.println(values[counter] + " cubed is " + cubedNumber);
    }
}
```

This is my code using the length() method:

```
/**
 * This method prints out a cubes from one to nine in descending order
 */
public static void cubes()
{
    // create a fixed length array and hard code index number
    int[] values = new int[9];
    values[0] = 1;
    values[1] = 2;
    values[2] = 3;
    values[3] = 4;
    values[4] = 5;
    values[5] = 6;
    values[6] = 7;
    values[7] = 8;
    values[8] = 9;
    // Create variable to store cubed numbers
    double cubedNumber = 0;
    // Create for loop to run the array from 1-9 in descending order
    for (int counter = 8; counter <= values.length; counter--)
    {
        cubedNumber = Math.pow(values[counter], 3);
        System.out.println(values[counter] + " cubed is " + cubedNumber);
    }
}
```

Which gives me the following error: "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at arraysPractice.cubes(arraysPractice.java:31)" I'm required to use the length method in my for loop. Am I using the length() method incorrectly? In both instances, the program still generates the cubes per this [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpOhA.png)

Comment: values.length is 9. This loop doesn't make sense. Why do you want to replace `> 0` with `<= values.length`? These are obviously not equivalent. You probably want to replace `counter = 8` with `counter = values.length - 1`.

Comment: I'm required to use values.length() method somewhere in the for loop, so I thought I had to use it there. I just tried the values.length - 1 and while it appears to work, I'm rather stumped as to why. What does it mean when to use the length() method minus a 1?

Comment: Well, values.length is 9. Not 0. It's the length of the array. You want to **start** your loop at the last index, which is equal to length - 1. Read my comment again.

Comment: Oh I think I'm beginning to understand. The loop is going in descending order so I need to start at -1 value, which is 9?

Comment: No, you don't want to start at -1. You want to start at 8, just like in your working loop. You start at 8 because it's the last index of the array, which has a length of 9. So, instead of hard-coding 8, you rather use values.length -1, so that, if you then decide to use an array of 20 elements, the loop continues to start at the last index, which would then be 19. Don't you realize that `length - 1` and `-1` are not the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
for (int counter = 8; counter <= values.length; counter--)
```

You're decrementing the counter;  it only goes lower over time.  It will always be `<= values.length`.

Eventually it will reach -1, and produce an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Maybe you want...

```
for (int counter = values.length - 1; counter >= 0; counter--)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is **counter <= values.length**

values.length have the value 9 and counter value starting decreasing from 8 to 7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0 and when its value reached at -1, still condition counter <= values.length is true for -1. And in this code

> cubedNumber = Math.pow(values[counter], 3);

When you pass -1 as index in values array, then it will give you the **java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException** Exception.

You loop in this way to made it run fine.

```
for (int counter = values.length - 1; counter >= 0; counter--)
{
    cubedNumber = Math.pow(values[counter], 3);
    System.out.println(values[counter] + " cubed is " + cubedNumber);
}
```